# It is possible to alter the $form_state['redirect'] of a previous submit callback?

Tags: php, drupal-7

```html
function module_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == "user_login"){             
       $form['#submit'][] =  'module_userlogin_callback';          
     }
}

function module_userlogin_callback($form, $form_state){
    global $base_url;
    $current_path = $base_url . '/' .'about';
    $form_state['redirect']=$current_path;
}
```

Thing is, the original submit callback user_login_submit  has already a $form_state['redirect'] to user profile page and i want to alter that and redirect to about page with out overriding the original submit callback function.is it possible?currently $form_state['redirect'] given by me is not working.how can i unset it and redirect to about page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar issue but I fixed it by writing my `form_alter` function in template.php, like this:

```html
your_theme_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
if ($form_id == 'user_login') {
         $form['#submit'][] = 'your_theme_userlogin_callback';
    }
}
function your_theme_userlogin_callback(&$form, &$form_state) {
   $form_state['redirect'] = '$url';//your redirect url path
}
```